# Count total association number on search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following many-to-many association...

```
class User
   has_and_belongs_to_many :starred_jobs, class_name: "Job",
                           join_table: "starred_jobs"
end

class Job
     has_and_belongs_to_many :starred_by, join_table: "starred_jobs",
                              class_name: "User"
end
```

In a query, I get number of users between two dates like

```
users = User.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
```

In a summary page, I want to view total number of jobs of selected users. Now, how I get the total number of jobs from searched users? For example:

```
@total_users_jobs = users.jobs.count
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest and maybe resource heavy method would be

```
users.map { |u| u.jobs.count }.sum
```

another method

```
JobUser.where("user_id in (?)", users.map(&:id)).count
```

Another

```
Job.joins(:users).where(users: {id: users.map(&:id)}.uniq.count
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your first statement return correct result but it is not efficient. In second and third statement it through exception. I have updated my question. I don't have any model like `JobUser`.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the total count of all Jobs for all matching Users

```
@total_users_jobs = Job.joins(:users).where(users: {id: users.map(&:id)}.uniq.count
```